# Supporting search queries in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Im currently trying to allow users to search my database from the client side and return the response to them. I'm a little confused on where in the view I need to support the search query, or if the way I'm going about it is even correct. I've done some research already and found out about the SearchFilter from DRF but unsure how to incorporate it into my code.

Here is my views for the resource i'm trying to search:

```
class Recipes(ViewSet):

  def list(self, request):

    recipes = Recipe.objects.all()

    user = self.request.query_params.get('user', None)

    if user is not None:
        recipes = recipes.filter(author = user)
    

    serializer = RecipeSerializer(recipes, many=True, context={'request': request})
    return Response(serializer.data)


def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
    try:
        recipe = Recipe.objects.get(pk=pk)
        serializer = RecipeSerializer(recipe, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)

    except Exception as ex:
        return HttpResponseServerError(ex)
```

Based on my research I've found that I can use:

```
serializer_class = RecipeSerializer
queryset = Recipe.objects.all()
filter_backends = (SearchFilter,)
filter_fields = ('title', 'ingredients')
```

in some way but i'm not exactly sure how. Any guidance is appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to do a simple equals query on your data? Similar to the lines you have:


if user is not None:
        recipes = recipes.filter(author = user)

Comment: @Programmingjoe yes I ended up just using a similar method that I used with the user.  Was over thinking the problem

Comment: Nice, yeah to start there's nothing wrong with having a bunch of if statements in the list method. If you want you can move generic ones into custom FilterClasses that you can add to FilterBackends to keep your code DRY